# if else statement not working in testcafe

Tags: testing, coded-ui-tests, testcafe

```
async selectLocalAdmin(){
    if(this.localAdmin.visible){
         await t.click(this.localAdmin);
    }
    else{
         console.log('not visible');
    }
```

}

I was trying to add some if else statements here and i observe that even when the if statment is true the click function is not happening, any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: which is `t` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Without a complete sample, I can only say that the `selector.visible` property returns a promise (assuming `localAdmin` is a `Selector`), so you need to add `await`:

```js
async selectLocalAdmin() {
    if (await this.localAdmin.visible) {
         await t.click(this.localAdmin);
    }
    else{
         console.log('not visible');
    }
}
```

If this does not fix the issue, please share the complete test code (include the URL of the tested application, which should be publicly accessible).